# AS3 -- Back Button Hardware?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm creating an app and need the back button *hardware* to function just like other apps where they go back to the screen you were on when you press them (or tap on Nexus devices, etc.)

When I hit the hardware back button on whatever I've made, it just backs out to the Android homescreen. That's not what I want to have happen. For example, if you're in an "options" menu, do what you need to do then hit the back button to go back to where you were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to control hardware Back key, you should subscribe for keyboard event with keyCode 94:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown, false, 0, true);

function onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent):void{
    if(e.keyCode == 94){
        //Stop default behaviour
        e.preventDefault();
        //perform your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply! 

It came up with the following, 

    Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 45, Line 5, Column 10 Warning: 1090: Migration issue: The onKeyDown event handler is not triggered automatically by Flash Player at run time in ActionScript 3.0.  You must first register this handler for the event using addEventListener ( 'keyDown', callback_handler).

I'm assuming this needs to be set at the beginning of the app, or something else?

Comment: This article should be helpful. It's about [event handling](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html)

Comment: For the record, using actual keycode values is not recommended and you should instead rely on the [`Keyboard`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Keyboard.html) class constants (if Adobe changes the value of a key, the constant would be updated. Additionally, it is much, much easier to maintain)